# Primeng how to center align the p-tabview headers

Tags: angular2-template, primeng

I am using Primeng p-tabview to create tabs. I need the tab headers to be aligned on the center as shown in the image. Can anyone help how to do this?

```
<div class="ui-g-12" style="height:100%;">
    <p-tabView class="analysisTab">
        <p-tabPanel header="TRADER">

        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="EVENTS" [selected]="true">

        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="SEARCH">

        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="NOTES">

        </p-tabPanel>
    </p-tabView>
</div>
```

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ui-tabview-nav list items are automatically floated to the left by the primeng css so you have to reset that and instead display them as inline-block, and to center menu items we have to add the attribute of text-align:center to the container, you can add the css like so (styles.css):

CSS

```
.ui-tabview {
    padding: .25em;
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-tabview .ui-tabview-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 .125em 1px 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block!important;
}
```

[Here a working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUUKWKGHCRhbrx4VVNsD?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much. It got centered, but the the active tab is moving down instead of stay on the same line like the other tabs. Any suggestion please? Thanks

Comment: try to remove class="analysisTab", here a working sample http://plnkr.co/edit/AUUKWKGHCRhbrx4VVNsD?p=preview